# How does C++ know how to cast to a certain type?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

If I write

```
long long int module = (long long int)GetModuleHandle(L"test.dll");
```

how does C++ know how to cast a HMODULE? As If I'm correct HMODULE should be a struct.

I understand how this works for basic types such as int, float and so on but
for programmer generated ones there must be like a translation, right?

Comment: The compiler just does what you ask with no concern for the consequences. Pointer to structure converted to `long long int`? You're the boss, you got it! Is the result valid? Not the compiler's problem, it's your problem. The only "conversion" that's performed is how the bits are interpreted via the type.

Comment: What does this say when you turn on more aggressive warnings, like `-Wall` or equivalent?

Comment: A `HMODULE` is a `void*`

Comment: `auto module = GetModuleHandle(L"test.dll");` -- No cast necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is not the same code though, because now `module` is an `HMODULE`. If you just wanted to remove the cast, you would write `HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(L"test.dll");`, i.e. `auto` actually solves nothing here... I'm not saying don't use it, necessarily, but it doesn't seem relevant to the issue of whether or not to have a cast. The cast was _never_ "necessary" in that sense.

Comment: @tadman It _has_ to be valid, at least in the sense that you can get the original `HMODULE` back without damage (and then use it). You don't know what representation it will have during its `long long int` days, but then you couldn't dereference that anyway so who cares :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings True, at least clang will say "cast from pointer to smaller type loses information".

Comment: @tadman _If_ you cast to a smaller type, yes. ;) `long long int` isn't going to be one, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it can't really, unless the code tells it how to, such as via a conversion operator or constructor.

There are a few built-in rules for primitive numerical things like `int` to `float`, or `void*` to `int`… though this latter example can only be done by a `reinterpret_cast` or a C-style cast like yours. That's because the conversion doesn't really make *logical* sense unless "you know best", which is what you're promising the compiler.

Indeed, like most handle types, [`HMODULE` is actually an alias for a pointer type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) (specifically, `void*`), though the things that `HMODULE`s point to will generally be of some class type. So you're casting a `void*` to a `long long int`, which is something the language's rules know how to do ([ref 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4), [ref 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4)).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can essentially force any area in accessible memory to be treated as you like by abusing the type system. For example, look at this garbled mess where I reinterpret a `const std::string` as a `const` pointer to a function from `int` to a `struct Foo` which contains a `vector<double>`. Now, if I try to do anything with `f`, it will crash magnificently, but even with `-Wall`, the code compiles and the only warning I get is that `f` is not used.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    std::vector<double> d{};
};

using func_type = const std::function<Foo(int)>*;

int main() {
    func_type f = reinterpret_cast<func_type>("This is a test");
}
```

Since, as someone pointed out, an `HMODULE` is just a `void*`, you can cast it to whatever you want. You're just taking its memory location and storing it in a `long long int`. I don't know why you'd want to do this, as it isn't useful.

Comment: This isn't _strictly_ accurate: you're not just jamming bits of memory into an integer. The conversion has logical, but implementation-defined semantics: _"A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type. The mapping function is implementation-defined. [Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. — end note]" ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4))_ Crucially, whatever mapping's chosen [must be reversible](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#5).

Comment: In practice though the compiler will probably do as you describe. :)